# GeoNodes: merging by distance only between different instance IDs

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have the following radial array node tree:

[image: radial array]
[image]

Currently it welds all duplicate verts.
I want it to behave like the Array modifier, only welding verts between instances, but not within the instance itself.
Not sure if this is possible at all. I know exactly how I'd go about doing this in Python, but the "selections" in GeoNodes are confusing to me for now. Selecting boundaries wouldn't be the solution though, for example.

Possible use cases: two-sided foliage for game assets, edges that become non-manifold when merged, using split edges for shading, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there is a "cheap" solution with vertex groups for this special problem (but it won't solve the "general" instance differentiating thing:

you could just use a vertex group like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So essentially just the VG will be welded.

result:

[image]

Comment: Hacky, but I can see it working in most practical cases. I'll wait to see if there's some other way and mark as answer. Is there a way to make it merge everything with no vertex group provided? I can think of subtracting a value of a "don't weld" group from 1, is there a better way?

Comment: i know another "dirty" solution which wouldn't need a vertex group, but i think even for that you would "wait" for a better answer...so...would be another waste of time for me ;)

Comment: I meant "give it time and mark yours as answer unless a cleaner solution appears", naturally.

Comment: no problem - i am sure there will be another cleaner answer ;) One hint: if you want to "tickle" the guys here: ask a question, give an absurd bad answer with another account and you will get the quickest answers here you have ever seen :D :D :D

Comment: How's [this](https://i.imgur.com/RJXzBbs.png) for "dirty"? Is that about what you had in mind? I imagine the same could be done for vertex indices, but there's no real way to loop through them, is there?

Comment: no, i had another idea in mind which actually would separate the instances.